# how use c dynamic library in linux kernel module

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I have to add a plugin to  a module  that runs in linux at kernel level   and I have to access to  an extern library that can be  changed  regularly without being able to stop the execution of this  Module

at userspace level , I know that we can use the dynamic library to make this kind of stuff .
And my question is : 
Can we  use this type of library at  kernel level , otherwise  is there  an equivalent of userspace level  dynamic library for  kernel

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a regular dynamic library in the kernel. However, kernel modules can be loaded and unloaded at runtime. So if you split your kernel code into long-running and dynamically reloadable parts, and link them into two separate kernel modules, you can achieve the same effect. Of course, your long-running kmod must not depend on the short-lived one; instead, you'll need the long running one to provide an interface that the reloadable module uses to register itself.